# C# for loop error > is invalid

Tags: c#, for-loop

I am trying to make a prime number generator.

I get three errors:

<21,22> expected >

<21,23> expression > is invalid

<21,24> expected ;

translated errors from norwegian. they may not be exact

```
using System;
namespace Primtall
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Generator G = new Generator();
        G.gen();
    }
}


public class Generator
{
    int a = 0;
    int divident = 0;

    public void gen()
    {
        for (a; a<100; a++;)
        {
            for (divident; divident <= 50;divident++)
            {
                int div = a/divident;
                if((div % 1) == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you highlight which lines the errors relate to?

Comment: remove ; after forloop

Comment: for a start you have an extra ; after a++

Comment: It helps to give us line numbers to go with the error messages (that reference line numbers).

Comment: also your for loops initialisers aren't initialising, so don't just put in the variable you want to use, set its initial value, so your int a = 0 can go in the for before the first ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare variables before loops, so you must leave empty first argument in `for`:

```
        for (; a < 100; a++)
        {
            for (; divident <= 50; divident++)
            {
```

Or better declare loop variables in loop:

```
        for (var a = 0; a < 100; a++)
        {
            for (var divident = 2; divident <= a / 2; divident++)
            {
```

Also, you have some problems in algorithm:

```
int div = a/divident;
if((div % 1) == 0)
```

Should be replaced with:

```
if((a % divident) == 0)
{
    flag = false;
    break;
}
```

Declare `flag` in first loop as `true` and check it after second loop finish. If it's stil `true` - number is prime. Also, start second loop with `2` and end with `a / 2`

Comment: Definitely the second option if the OP ever wants to call the method more than once.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to define a and divident variables as fields. You make no use of them except in the loop. In fact, using class members (fields) as loop variables will immediately render your class as "not thread safe", becuase if two seperate threads execute the gen() method on the same Generator instance they will both fail to get correct results

Change your Generator class like this: (divident starting from 1 to avoid divide by zero exception)

```
public class Generator
{
    public void gen()
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < 100; a++)
        {
            for (int divident = 1; divident <= 50; divident++)
            {
                int div = a / divident;
                if ((div % 1) == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misunderstanding how for loops work

for(Initialise; While; Action)

so in english what you are asking it to do is

for
a where a starts at 0

while a less than 100

perform body

then increment a by 1

this in code is

```
For(int a = 0;a<100;a++)
{
    //body
}
```